sshd_config password login disable settings not respected
I'm trying to configure a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS box to be accessible using public-private keypair only.
As usual I've configured the following two settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
# <other settings as default>

I've removed any /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf files so they do not interfere with it.
However, running sshd -T shows that kbdinteractiveauthentication is set to yes. Where is this setting coming from?
# sshd -T
passwordauthentication no
permitemptypasswords no
usepam yes
kbdinteractiveauthentication yes  <-- where is this coming from?

sshd_config
Here is the sshd_config file I'm using with all the comments (lines starting with #) removed.
PermitRootLogin no

PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 3
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server


As a workaround, I've added AuthenticationMethods publickey into the sshd_config. I do not understand where sshd is getting that configuration value for kbdinteractiveauthentication from however.

kbdinteractiveauthentication yes  <-- where is this coming from? — that's what you have to figure out. In the end, that might permit authentication with passwords after all, providing the generic chat-like authentication mechanism. One hint, if your sshd_config has Include, look into whatever is included. Other hint, you have to watch out for other incantations of KbdInteractiveAuthentication in sshd_config or its includes. Only the first one has effect, all others won't override it.

And, also, KbdInteractiveAuthentication might be influenced by ChallengeResponseAuthentication (it's not a nickname; the former has the default value set to the actual value of the latter, which default is yes). Check that too.

That's a good shout. I had a look for that option but did not find it in the sshd_config. I've included my full sshd_config file - excluding comments - in case that can help identify the issue.

This doesn't look like derived from the default ubuntu 20.04 sshd_config (as obtained from the package). The proper default config from that package does have the line Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf as the first effective (non-commented) line (essential to permit files in said directory to override anything). Are you sure your doesn't? Also, it says ChallengeResponseAuthentication no instead of KbdInteractiveAuthentication no; what was the point of changing it?

Yes I removed both the files inside that directory as well as that line itself (to make sure it wasn't interfering with the settings I am aiming for).
The note on KbdInteractiveAuthentication instead of ChallengeResponseAuthentication is a good point. I will test this out shortly.

It's better to put all your alterations into some .conf file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/ instead of editing sshd_config. It serves exactly for that purpose.

We normally do but due to the issue described I tried to eliminate anything that could interfere with it. I believe your note is actually correct on the wrong usage of KbdInteractiveAuthentication for Ubuntu 20 (works for 22 and later). I'm making a reproducable case for this now to confirm it.
